# Attempted to call function "iconv_strlen"

Tags: symfony

I have just installed Manjaro Linux and suddenly, using this system, I am getting this error. I did not do anything for few days and it was working perfectly in Debian. The full error is:

> Attempted to call function "iconv_strlen" from namespace "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Logger".

And also

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException: "Attempted to call function "iconv_strlen" from namespace "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Logger"." at /home/gabriel/NetBeansProjects/CasaDoGesso/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Logger/DbalLogger.php line 102

What do I do?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your errors? In what conditions are you receiving it? What do you call before receiving these errors?

Comment: @FalconUA I just enter in the project folder, I enter `bin/console server:run` and I access `localhost:8000`. That's it.

Comment: @FalconUA Besides, I tried to create a new project using `symfony new project`, moved all my files and still the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems in Manjaro/Arch I had to uncomment the `iconv.so` exention in `/etc/php/php.ini`. Now it is working.

Comment: I do it, but: **UndefinedFunctionException: Attempted to call function “iconv” from namespace**